# Allow only 1 POST of each dropdown value in PHP form

Tags: php, html, database, post, mysqli

I have a simple PHP form to insert "models" (in dorpdown) with a price.
The thing I want to do is that you can only post model 1 once and model 2 once etc.. 
So if you choose model 1 in the dropdown and post it and try it again that it doesn't allow you because you already posted model 1.

sorry for my bad English

```
        <select name="model">
        <?  
        $modellen[1]= "Model 1";
        $modellen[2]= "Model 2";
        $modellen[3]= "Model 3";

        foreach ($modellen as $key => $value) 
        {
            echo "<option value='".$key."''>".$value."</option>";
        }
        ?>
        </select>


if(isset($_POST['toevoegen'])) 
    {
        $prijs = Safesql($_POST['prijs']);
        $moment = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
        $kiesmodel = Safesql($_POST['model']);
        if(!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO prijzen (prijs, created, model) VALUES (".$prijs.",'".$moment."' , '".$kiesmodel."')")) {echo $mysqli->error;}
        else{ echo "het toevoegen is gelukt";} 
        Laden(0);
    }



 //show records from database
if ($query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM prijzen")) { echo $mysqli->error;}

if ($query->num_rows >= 1) 
    {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            ?><tr><td><form action="index.php" method="post">
            <? echo "Model" . " " . $row['model']; ?><a href="index.php?verwijderen=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="delete.png"></a>
            <a href="index.php?edit=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="edit.png"></a><?
            echo "  prijs:" . $row['prijs']. "<br>" ."";?><?
        }
    }
```

Comment: then check if it was selected already before you do the new insert. What is the problem?

Comment: Why not add a status column in db and flag the model as checked. the next time you populate the dropdown menu just populate with only models with unchecked status or add a disable property to the models with checked status.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try add validation before insert,

```
if(isset($_POST['toevoegen'])) 
{
    $prijs = Safesql($_POST['prijs']);
    $moment = date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
    $kiesmodel = Safesql($_POST['model']);

    // validation
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM prijzen WHERE model = '$kiesmodel'";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    if (count($row) >= 1) {
        echo "<script>alert('You already add this model')</script>";
    }else{
        if(!$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO prijzen (prijs, created, model) VALUES (".$prijs.",'".$moment."' , '".$kiesmodel."')")) {echo $mysqli->error;}
        else{ echo "het toevoegen is gelukt";} 
        Laden(0);
    }      

}
```

may it can help you

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, the only problem is it gives instantt alert even if nothing is in my database (model)

Comment: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: happy to hear that